# Google Form Google Apps Script answer validation for logical errors

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-forms

If i create a question in a grid form say.. 
qn: "if price increase by the following amount, will you still buy?"
options:
5%              Yes           No (choose either yes or no)
10%             Yes           No (choose either yes or no)
15%             Yes           No (choose either yes or no)

and i want to create an answer validation such that if a user choose "No" for 5% and choose "Yes" for 10% and 15%, it will have an error message that say ("logical error")

What would be the right code to use?

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding  any private or confidential information), and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: i am not using spreadsheet, is just directly coding on the google form.. something like the grid validation

Comment: what i mean is if the user is filling out the form and this logical error happens, it can immediately tell the user that the answer he/she is filling is wrong

Comment: I don't believe that Google Forms offers that - validation is limited to 'one response per column'. But you do it with a webapp.

Comment: What do u mean webapp?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is no way of implementing this sort of validations using Forms. The only options you have is:

1. Explaining your restrictions on your form, and using an `onFormSubmit` event to filter out responses that do not match your criteria. Using this option however, the user is still able to submit the form and will not receive any feedback telling him his submission is not correct.
2. Using a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). The idea of this one is to implement a basic [form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) using HTML. The restrictions you described could then be verified using Javascript, and the results can be published into a Google Sheets document of your choice. This option however, will clearly take more effort. You can see an example of creating a form using WebApps [here](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/google-appscript-create-form-using-html-publish-form-as-webapp-email-response/).