# Real time google forms validation using app scripts

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form where individuals are inputting two numbers via dropdowns: 1) Required Base Salary, 2) Total Target Compensation. Using app scripts I would like to have real time validation to insure that Total Target Comp is greater than or equal to Required Base Salary right after they make their selections. Is this even possible?

Comment: There is no way to interact programmatically with Google Forms until after submission.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Form Google Apps Script answer validation for logical errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59015878/google-form-google-apps-script-answer-validation-for-logical-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't interact with a Form answer until that answer is submitted. As a workaround, you could split the quizz into two forms. The first Form would include the *Required Base Salary*, while the second Form would ask for the *Total Target Compensation* based on the results of the first Form. As an alternative you could warn the user about the correct values on the question description (and send him an email warning about incorrect values after the answer is submitted). Additionally you could set up [data validation rules](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en#zippy=%2Cshort-answer) to prevent bad values.